# Person-swap movie/episode where girls are replaced by copies

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I'm trying to remember the name of a movie/series episode where girls are sent to an institution for being rebellious, at this institution they will be corrected. Three girls sharing a bedroom become friends and decide to leave. They know they put sleeping drugs in the milk at night, so they don't drink it the last night.

While trying to escape, they discover that the institution is making copies of them by doing several surgeries on other girls that will replace them. The main character escapes and with her double they take revenge on the people that sent them there.

Comment: See also *Point Blanc* by Anthony Horowitz, the second book of the Alex Rider series, which features an epinomous school that replaces boys by lookalikes in the same manner.

Comment: @b_jonas Pretty sure that R. L. Stein did something pretty similar with Clones at one point too

Comment: Also seems to owe a lot to [The Stepford Wives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stepford_Wives).

Comment: FYI if you are into plots like this, I highly recommend the 2013 movie `Coherence` to you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This must surely be [Paradise Hills](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6127004/), a film released in 2019. "Paradise Hills" is a type of reformatory, set on a remote island. A girl who is making trouble for her parents is sent there, and as you say, shares a bedroom with two other girls. There are indeed drugged at night, with sedatives placed in their milk. They assume that they are there for their behavior to be corrected, but in fact they are being studied so that lookalikes, prepared by plastic surgery, can take their place and convincingly imitate them.